# Generate two random numbers first number smaller than second php

Tags: php, random, numbers, range, conditional-statements

I need to generate two Random numbers using PHP. This is simple but the condition is that the first number should be smaller than second number in value.

So let's say I need to generate lower and upper bounds between 10 and 1000. So I will need two random numbers within this range. First number as lower bound (20 may be) and upper bound higher than that in value so (100 may be).

Thanks
Ahmar.

Comment: Why can't you just reverse the order of the numbers after generating both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$num1 = rand(20, 999);
$num2 = rand($num1+1, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Liew. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$smaller = mt_rand(10, 999); // This generates a number between 10 and 999.
$bigger = mt_rand($smaller+1, 1000); // generates a bigger number up to 1000 based on the smaller number
```

Is there anything wrong with just generating two numbers between 10 and a thousand and then ordering them? Or does the size of the second one have to be dependent on the first? Because if not,

```
$rand = mt_rand(10, 999);
$rand2 = mt_rand(10, 999);
while($rand === $rand2) $rand2 = mt_rand(10, 999);
$bigger = max($rand, $rand2);
$smaller = min($rand, $rand2);
```

Comment: That will do nicely. Thanks a lot.